# making the gridview smaller using bootstrap stylesheet

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I want to make the Gridview in asp.net web forms a little bit smaller and centered using bootstrap stylesheets. below is my code:

```
      <table class="table table-sm " >
                       
                <asp:GridView   ID="grdTest"  runat="server" GridLines="Horizontal"  CssClass="table  table-sm table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive-sm table-hover table-striped" >   
                </asp:GridView>
                            
                        </table>
```

below is the image of the bootstrap table:

[image]

how can I make it smaller and centered on the screen? Right now, it is stretching the entire content page.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a wrapper with *'table-responsive'*

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
...
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: when I put the wrapper of table responsiveness as a wrapper. I can see the outline of the actual width of the table, but the actual table is squeezed in the corner. Is thier any way this can be fixed.